# for loop to calculate mean value

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have an excel sheet of 41 columns and 513 rows. I want to use a loop which will calculate the mean of 4 columns. The interval is i = 2:4:41. I need help with writing down the loop.

```
for i = 2:4:41
    the formula for the mean calculation, V()=V()/41;
end
```

Need help with the formula.

Comment: Need help with your home work? How about you try it yourself and come back with the basic code first?

Comment: I did my basic homework already. However, I was stuck hence the question was put up.

Comment: @Sai in general homework questions are discouraged on Stack Overflow, unless accompanied by a proper try and well-written question statement with where the problem is. I took the liberty of writing a short piece of code anyhow, try and learn from it. I won't explain you everything in detail, as you still have to learn how to actually write codes like these yourself for your class.

Comment: @Adriaan - This wasn't for a class homework. I am working on patient data analysis. Agreed that my approach of the question wasn't clear enough, will improve henceforth.

Comment: This code does not calculate mean of four columns. This calculates the mean of every forth column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`mean`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) functionality to do this:

```
DataMatrix = rand(513,41);

ColMean = zeros(length(DataMatrix),numel(2:4:37)); % initialise output
range = 2:4:37;
for ii = 1:numel(range)  %go to 37, otherwise it'll fail
    ColMean(:,ii) = mean(DataMatrix(:,range(ii):range(ii)+3),2);
end
```

I'll leave it up to you to explain to your teacher how you initialised vectors and how you used the `range` for the `for` loop.

Comment: I thought he "Need help with the formula" - should have just written `(V(1)+V(2)+V(3)+V(4)) / 4` good answer nevertheless

Comment: @dasdingonesin What? You are doing the same question as the OP?

Comment: @GameOfThrows No. I just wanted to make OP's life even easier by relieving him of the burden to post a comment like this when he finds out that verbatim copying the code in this answer won't get him any points on his homework assignment.